# How to check if/else once for all functions instead of putting it in every function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, control-flow

So basically I have four functions: `moveUp()`, `moveDown()`, `moveRight()`, and `moveLeft()` that move the user's position in a 4x4 2d array. To check if the user has reached the goal position, I use this statement

```
if (agentPos[0] == goalPos[0] && agentPos[1] == goalPos[1]) {
    console.log('goal reached');
}
```

Now if I put this if/else block of code inside every move function, my program works as intended, but if I do it like this, it does not:

```
function moveUp() {
    ...
}
function moveRight() {
    ...
}
function moveDown() {
    ...
}
function moveLeft() {
    ...
}

if (agentPos[0] == goalPos[0] && agentPos[1] == goalPos[1]) {
    console.log('goal reached');
}
```

How do I use the if/else block without repeating it within every move function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap it in a function and call that at the end:

```
function check()
{
    if (agentPos[0] == goalPos[0] && agentPos[1] == goalPos[1]) {
        console.log('goal reached');
    }
}

function moveLeft() {
    ...
    check();
}
```

You could also create higher order functions that return functions that have the check built in.

```
const check = logic => () =>
{
    logic();

    if (agentPos[0] == goalPos[0] && agentPos[1] == goalPos[1]) {
        console.log('goal reached');
    }
};

const moveLeft = check(() => {
    // logic here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a function and call it:

```
function goalCheck() {
    if (agentPos[0] == goalPos[0] && agentPos[1] == goalPos[1]) {
        console.log('goal reached');
    } 
}

function moveUp() {
    ...
    goalCheck();
    ...
}
```

This is only so easy because your check relies entirely on globals, and on side effects to operate. You may want to revisit that design choice later, but for now, that's all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create one function for the check you reached your goal or not as below.

```
function moveUp() {
    goleReached(agentPos, goalPos)
}
function moveRight() {
    goleReached(agentPos, goalPos)
}
function moveDown() {
    goleReached(agentPos, goalPos)
}
function moveLeft() {
    goleReached(agentPos, goalPos)
}

function goleReached(agentPos, goalPos) {
    if (agentPos[0] == goalPos[0] && agentPos[1] == goalPos[1]) {
        console.log('goal reached');
    }
}
```